# How to have Angular2-MDL-ext Select placeholder grayed out

Tags: angular2-mdl

Is it possible to have the select placeholder grayed out coherently with other Angular 2 MDL form fields?

This is what I can obtain with default settings:

```
<mdl-textfield type="text" label="CAP..." formControlName="postcode" floating-label></mdl-textfield><br>
<mdl-textfield type="text" label="Città..." formControlName="city" floating-label></mdl-textfield><br>
<mdl-textfield type="text" label="Provincia..." formControlName="province" floating-label></mdl-textfield><br>
<mdl-select
      placeholder="Nazione"
      formControlName="countryid">
   <mdl-option value="0"></mdl-option>
   <mdl-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</mdl-option>
</mdl-select>
```

[image]

The select placeholder "Nazione" appears in black. I'd like to have it grayed out just as the field "Cap...", "Città...", "Provincia...".

Comment: can you create a plnkr? here is a template http://plnkr.co/edit/I3dLfLUDIH2xlEJqj0da?p=preview.

Comment: Here the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3GHZHgxOGhDdrfAQHlv2?p=preview
I'm not able to have mdl-select fully working in the Plnkr: it stays always opened, but it's working in my local app.

Comment: Do you plan to support Reactive Forms with mdl-select? At this time when I query a form containing a mdl-select component the property returns always the default value.

Comment: ok. got it! the mdl-select did not support floating labels - only placeholder. you should create an enhancement issue in https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext.

Comment: please add this (reactive forms) as a requirement in the issue

Comment: I will open an issue, but notice that my request is not related to floating labels. Check my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3GHZHgxOGhDdrfAQHlv2?p=preview , I removed the floating label, but the mdl-select placeholder label is shown in black instead of gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdl2-angular-ext 0.6.0 should have proper placeholders now. You example code is correct, but for anyone else visiting this question, here's the code (again):

`<mdl-select
      placeholder="Nazione"
      formControlName="countryid">
   <mdl-option value="0"></mdl-option>
   <mdl-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</mdl-option>
</mdl-select>`

Unrelated to your question, but since it was discussed in the comments regarding the question, the floating-label property works now too.

`<mdl-select floating-label
      placeholder="Nazione"
      formControlName="countryid">
   <mdl-option value="0"></mdl-option>
   <mdl-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</mdl-option>
</mdl-select>`